# Creating a filled contour plot using data in lists

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, contour

I have a data set that consists of 3 columns in a .csv file. The first 2 columns are map co-ordinates and the third is the percentage of zinc found in a borehole at the corresponding map co-ordinates. I would like to create a contour map to show the Zn concentration changes with distance. All of the examples of code I have been able to find use data in the form of a matrix, whereas mine are in lists. I have tried several different ways of plotting this which I have shown underneath, the majority of methods give me error messages along the lines of "object x not found" which I think is to do with the layout of my data. Does anyone know how to do this? I have added a similar data set to mine below. Thanks for any help in advance.
Holly

Data set:

```
Statsrep <- structure(list(X = c(156000L, 156010L, 156421L, 156450L, 156500L, 156700L, 158420L, 158646L, 158970L, 159050L, 159050L, 159130L, 159155L), Y = c(143630, 143980, 147260, 145000, 146000, 142800, 146700, 145207, 147170, 145200, 144800, 147815, 145890), Zn = c(2, 8, 4, 0, 3, 0, 2, 7, 12, 0, 4, 19, 0)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Zn"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L), class = "data.frame")
Statsrep
```

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
Grade <- read.csv(file="filename.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
ggplot(Grade, aes(x$x="X", y$y="Y", z$z="Zn")) +
stat_contour()

library(lattice)
Grade <- read.csv(file="filename.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
levelplot(Grade ~x*y, data = Zn,
xlab = "Eastings", ylab = "Northings",
col.regions = terrain.colours)

Grade <- read.csv(file="filename.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
x$x <- X
y$y <- Y
z$z <- Zn
filled.contour(x$x, y$y, z$z, color = terrain.colours,
xlab = "Eastings", ylab = "Northings"),
plot.axes = {axis(1, seq(156000, 165000, by=1000)); axis(2, seq(142000, 150000, by=1000))},
key.title = title(main="Zn content\n(percent)"),
key.axes= axis(4, seq(0, 20, by = 2)))
```

Answer (score 8):

Working with ggplot2, you can create a contour plot with your example data set using:

```
ggplot(Statsrep, aes(x=X, y=Y, z=Zn)) + 
    geom_density2d()
```

to give

[image]

You had a couple of problems with the `ggplot2` code. In particular, where you set the aesthetics you had:

```
aes(x$x="X", y$y="Y", z$z="Zn")
```

Comment: Ah so I was just using the wrong function. This works but is it possible to fill between the lines with colour?

Comment: Try: `g + stat_density2d(aes(fill=..density..), contour=FALSE, geom="tile")`

Comment: Thank you! When the two are combined that is definitely the type of plot I'm looking for. However, the key for the density doesn't give the value of zinc, it gives values of e-08

Comment: I'm not quite sure the best way of doing that (I've got a few ideas, but not entirely sure what you would want). What about asking another question?

Comment: Okey dokey. Thank you very much for your help!